# Saving Screen Region Configuration

Tags: linux, ssh, gnu-screen

I was wondering, as I couldn't find it in the man page, if there is a way for the linux [screen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) command to remember the configuration of regions when you disconnect and reconnect. Basically if I run 4 windows in 4 regions, what can I do with screen so that when reconnect to this screen it will set up those 4 regions the same way they were when I disconnected on the same windows in each screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that what I was looking for was the layout command which was not listed in the online version of the man page I was looking at but was present in the local man page. Basically use C-a :`layout save [name]` to save the layout to a name and `layout autosave on` so that it will be saved when you detach. It will automatically be reapplied when you reattach with the same region and window configuration.